# Get npmAuthToken instead of npmAuthIdent from Azure DevOps to use with semantic-release and yarnv3

Tags: azure, npm, yarnpkg, semantic-release

we probably have a really specific case. We are using

- Private NPM registry on Azure DevOps
- Yarn v1
- Semantic-Release Monorepo (containing multiple packages. I think if it would only be one package, it would be ok)

Everything works fine and as expected, we now want to update to Yarn v3, but this is where the issue arises

`semantic-release`, per default, uses `npm` to create releases. It also uses `.npmrc`, if available to authenticate against the private registry.

However, since `yarn v3`, the `.npmrc` is not supported anymore, so it doesn't exist and also, while `npm` creates the same `yarn.lock` as `yarn v1` it doesn't create the same `yarn.lock` as `yarn v3`

So, now we are facing the following issue

When running our pipeline our semantic-release fails, because it is changing the lockfile (we tested this locally, and the lockfile is indeed changed), because `semantic-release` internally uses `npm` with a plugin and this plugin which formats the yarn.lock to an outdated format and then fails to deploy multiple packages

To solve this, we found the following library https://github.com/dmeents/semantic-release-yarn/

however, this library requires that we set an `NPM_TOKEN` so `yarn` can authenticate with it.  With the `npm plugin`, it checked for an `.npmrc` and used this one to authenticate, but since this doens't exist anymore, the new package searches for `NPM_TOKEN`.

However, I have not found any way how too get `NPM_TOKEN` from Microsoft Azure DevOps. In the `.yarnrc.yml` we are using the `npmAuthIdent` which you can see here has the wrong format

```
Defines the authentication credentials to use by default when accessing your registries (equivalent to _auth in the v1). This settings is strongly discouraged in favor of npmAuthToken.
npmAuthIdent: "username:password"

Defines the authentication credentials to use by default when accessing your registries (equivalent to _authToken in the v1). If you're using npmScopes to define multiple registries, the npmRegistries dictionary allows you to override these credentials on a per-registry basis.
npmAuthToken: "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff"
```

https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#npmAuthIdent

---

As I see it, there are 3 possible solutions

- Migrate back to yarn v1 (Least preferred solution)
- Find out how to get such an npmAuthToken using Azure DevOps (Most preferred solution)
- Create our own plugin for `semantic-release` to suppoort `yarn` in combination with `Azure DevOps`

Do you have any idea how to solve this or maybe someone already faced this issue?

Comment: For now, I have created a PR https://github.com/dmeents/semantic-release-yarn/pull/4 in the custom library that should add support for npmAuthIdent